# Dynamic content layout structure with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, layout, dynamic-data

Unfortunately, my boss decided that our news site's home page layout should be like http://dailymail.co.uk

But I couldn't find a solution for their "dynamic layout". They use full one column image/posts, two columns of short/small images/titles, half column image/post in an unordered column. I couldn't find a way to do that.

There are two "solutions" crossed my mind:

- Choose a "template" for each news item. And show them according to this template. For example: "With Big Image / Full Column", "Align Right half of the column" or "Normal" etc. But as you can see from daily mail's layout these will create lots of work for editors.
- Create a "Drag and Drop" based area, where an editor can arrange news with a few options. But this will create another problems for me.

If needed I can change DB structure. But for now it's very simple and I'm willing to keep it that way. Also it would be very nice to keep layout options separate from news table.

Could anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

can you use a grid system like this: http://960.gs/

I didn't use something like this but I think storing classnames in database and using them in this grid type templates might help you.

Comment: CSS is the easy part. My problem is data structure. I'll give an example. When adding new item editor will have to choose a post template (big, half column, small etc.). Based on this template she/he also have choose a "template image". Then have to decide where to put this item on home page. I have to query posts based on: a) Post positon, b) Post template, c) Post order (date). For this example I have to add at least 3 columns to news table, and lots of selects for home page. If a new post added, editor should also rearrange other posts. I'm looking better ideas to avoid that.

Comment: I would have a 5-6 column design with 960 grid system and make the editor to choose how many grids wide would the post be, and save the decisions to somewhere. and the layouts will be having 4+1 on slider line, 1+1+1+1+1 on the news grid, 3+2 on the wide sidebar line etc. and if the item is 4 boxes wide, it'll show on slider box, if 2 boxes wide,it'll show on wide sidebar etc.

Comment: and here's something i found. maybe will be useful (drag one box and see the result) : http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/drag-drop-panels/

Comment: thank you very much. As I said, front end/CSS is easy part. (I knew "Drag&Drop Panels" tutorial) There are 3 ways in my mind: 1) Item based positioning, 2) "Box" based positioning, 3) Keeping home page separate (drag & drop based layout design). But every one of these have their own problems. I'm trying to help editor. 1) I explained in my first comment, 2) There will be "lots" of boxes and has to be static (for example 10 boxes on home page), 3) For every new added item editor has to rearrange home page design. I think I'll go with a mix of 1 and 2. Again thanks for your efforts.